# I am trying to use Sequelize with Next JS API routes

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, next.js

I am trying to use Sequelize with Next JS API routes... but I am falling over at almost the first hurdle.

No matter what I do, I don't seem to be able to import the model into my route.js file.

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect'
const {models} = require('../../models')


const handler = nextConnect()
.post(async (req, res) => {
    const { qname, qanswer } = req.body
    const question = await  models.Question.create({ qname, qanswer })
    res.statusCode = 200
    return res.json({ status: 'success' })
})
export default handler
```

No matter what I try and do "models" is always undefined. I am pretty new to node js and and I suspect I am doing something basic wrong but for the life of me, I do not know what!

I believe the relative path is correct. The route.js file is sitting at ./Pages/API / route.js and pages sits at the same level as the Models directory.

Model appears to be defined correctly, I used the CLI command to build the model and running the following code...

```
const {sequelize} = require('./models')
async function main(){
    await sequelize.sync({force: true})
}

main()
```

inside App.js (which is in the root folder) successfully built the db - which makes me think I have that bit correct. Essentially I am pretty much using the boiler plate code provided by the CLI command.

One thing I have noticed... when I call the restful endpoint - I see Next JS report the following...

```
warn  - ./Models/index.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

Which I suspect is somehow related to me problem!!!:)

Lastly, I should say that I have tried combinations of trying IMPORT instead of REQUIRE and with, and without curly braces - in desperation!

Thanks is advance for any help...

model definition is provided below in case it is useful context..

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Questions extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  Questions.init({
    qname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    qanswer: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'questions',
  });
  return Questions;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

i figure it out! after so many searching clue in google. i dont know if u already solve your problem but i hope this will help other who stuck in same problem.

first of all, make sure your model is work with migration command. I generate sequelize default folder and file using

```
npx sequelize-cli init
```

and this is my user model gererate using sequelize-cli command (table name in database is "users")

```
// models/users.js
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Users extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.belongsTo(models.UsersTypes, {
          foreignKey: 'user_type_id',
      });
      
    }
  }
  Users.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: sequelize.fn('uuid_generate_v4'),
      primaryKey: true
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(35),
      unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_login: DataTypes.DATE,
    employee_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    is_block: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    is_active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'users',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  });
  
  return Users;
};
```

then update your index.js model (custom with your model, im using user model as example)

```
// models/index.js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js')[env];
const db = {};

const Users = require('./users'); //define your model here

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.Users = Users(sequelize, Sequelize); // add this line, without this, not gonna work in next step

module.exports = db;
```

then in your api routes

```
'use strict';

import db from '../../../models/index';
db.sequelize.sync();
const Users = db.Users;

export default async function handler(req, res) {

  const {body, headers} = req;
  const {username, password} = body;

  if (!username || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({"message":"Missing username/password"});
  }

  try {
    await db.sequelize.authenticate();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({"message":"Unable to connect to the database:", error});
  }

  const users = await Users.findAll();      

  res.status(200).json({ users })
}
```

i get the result

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "35479f7c-80aa-480e-9ad9-92262f527b19",
            "username": "yosiazwan",
            "password": "$2a$06$dxmTHstIjAM3.d1.SUE5mey7qnQZ2icYnKmWcboitr6J59LOdZMRW",
            "last_login": null,
            "employee_id": null,
            "is_block": false,
            "is_active": true,
            "created_at": "2022-07-26T07:38:55.874Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-07-26T07:38:55.874Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

i get the clue from here
https://techsolutionshere.com/next-js-with-sequelize-and-postgresql/

**Edit : I find better solutions**

```
// models/index.js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const modelPath = process.cwd() + '/models/'; //add this line
const basename = path.basename(__dirname + '/../models/index.js'); //change this line
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js')[env];

const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(modelPath) //change this line
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(__dirname + '/../models/' + file)(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes); //change this line
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

explanation:

```
// for fs read absolute path, using "__dirname + '/../models/'" not working
const modelPath = process.cwd() + '/models/'; //add this line

// using __filename as basename not work because will return api route file instead, 
// we need index.js as value
const basename = path.basename(__dirname + '/../models/index.js');

//fs read modelPath
fs
  .readdirSync(modelPath)

// "__dirname + '/../models/' + file" must always insert in require function
// if above value is use as const or other variable not gonna working
const model = require(__dirname + '/../models/' + file)(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
```

**Correction :**

in models/users.js i define

```
modelName: 'users'
```

but better change to

```
tableName: 'users'
```

because better for Table Name is lowercase and Model Name is CamelCase

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if anyone spent time looking at this. Model is defined as Question**s** .. I was using Question.... I guess with so much new stuff to get my head around, I am missing the basics!!:)