# Sequelize Function "findAll" in Next.js is undefined

Tags: api, express, next.js, sequelize.js, backend

I am trying to fetch data from the database using sequelize in nextjs, models are created successfully, also the migration works fine.
I am building endpoints but seems the function is undefined.
Table name on database is "users"

**Model: user.js**

```
 "use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");

// Fields to hide in the response
const PROTECTED_ATTRIBUTES = ["password", "token"];

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    toJSON() {
      // hide protected fields
      let attributes = Object.assign({}, this.get());
      for (let a of PROTECTED_ATTRIBUTES) {
        delete attributes[a];
      }
      return attributes;
    }

    static associate({ Category, Job, Application }) {
      // define association here
      this.hasMany(Category, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "categories" });
      this.hasMany(Job, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "jobs" });
      this.hasMany(Application, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "applications" });
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      surname: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
      password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      avatar: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
      role: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, defaultValue: 3 },
      dob: { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: false },
      description: DataTypes.TEXT,
      cv: DataTypes.TEXT,
    },

    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "User",
    }
  );
  return User;
};
```

**api/test.js**

```
const { User } = require("../../models");

export default function handler(req, res) {
  //   res.status(200).json({ name: "John Doe" });
  const users = User.findAll({ limit: 10 }); //TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined
  res.status(200).json({ users });
}
```

Comment: Look my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73132197/6048105

Answer (score 0):

You should init the model first.

```
const DataTypes = require("sequelize").DataTypes;
const _User = require("./User");
const initModels = (sequelize) => {
const User = _User(sequelize, DataTypes);
 return {
    User
 };
}
module.exports = { initModels };
```

then you can get the model and call the findAll function

```
const initModels = require("./models/init-models");
...
const models = initModels(sequelize);
models.User.findAll({ where: { username: "..." }});
```